# ImportError: No module named bs4 how fix

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, debian

I have next python 2.7 (debian) code

```
import sys
import random
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from YandexDiskException import YandexDiskException
from YandexDiskRestClient import YandexDiskRestClient
```

I try run, but get this message

```
root@vps-1074211:/tmp/beautifulsoup4-4.4.0# python /var/vah13/untitled/grep.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/vah13/untitled/grep.py", line 5, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: No module named bs4
```

how fix it?

I installed

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
apt-get install python-bs4
```

Comment: You're saying that after doing `pip install beautifulsoup4` that it still didn't work, or that `pip install beautifulsoup4` didn't work?

Comment: after pip install beautifulsoup4 don't work, pip command was finished success

Comment: Could you provide the error pip has shown you? Given that pip install has failed, your machine doesn't have the library bs4. Most common cause I can think of is misconfigured proxy

Comment: Does `locate python | grep beautiful ` show you anything of interest?

Comment: `/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.1.0.egg-info
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.1.0.egg-info
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.4.0.egg-info
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.4.0.egg-info/PKG-INFO
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.4.0.egg-info/SOURCES.txt
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.4.0.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.4.0.egg-info/installed-files.txt`

Comment: `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.4.0.egg-info/requires.txt
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.4.0.egg-info/top_level.txt
/usr/share/doc/python-beautifulsoup
/usr/share/doc/python-beautifulsoup/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/python-beautifulsoup/copyright
/var/cache/apt/archives/python-beautifulsoup_3.2.1-1_all.deb
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-beautifulsoup.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-beautifulsoup.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-beautifulsoup.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-beautifulsoup.prerm`

Comment: `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python-bs4 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Comment: And `python --version` ?

Comment: version - Python   2.7.10

Comment: Add at the top of your file: `#!/usr/bin/env python2.7`

Comment: I change `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` to `from  BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup`, remove V4 and install V3, all work

Comment: @ Vahagn to add information to your question (e.g. the output of `locate python`), please *update your question*, rather than using *comments*. if you have found a solution, please add an *answer* (to your own question), so the question is properly marked as *resolved*.